# How does cushioning reduce pressure?

Tags: pressure

Why does a padded strap of a bag cause less pressure on the shoulder as compared to another bag with a strap of the same surface area that is not padded. The weight of the bag and the area of the strap are same in both scenarios. As P = F/ A, pressure should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

The overall weight that you have to carry is the same. The average pressure is also the same. However, the distribution of the pressure does not need to be the same. You actually have
$$ \Delta P(x) = \frac{F(x)}{\Delta A} \,,$$
where $\Delta P(x)$ is the little bit of pressure below the little surface patch $\Delta A$. And it might happen that the pressure is very high in some regions and lower in other regions.

Take a look at the heatmap of the [weight distribution of a saddle](http://bisaddle.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/chair-map.png). You see that the rider has his weight supported by the horse. But the weight is not uniformly distributed on the horse's back but there are spots with more pressure.

It is the same effect you have when walking with shoes on. The pressure is distributed more evenly and there are no “sharp” points.

Answer (score 0):

No, a soft cushion pad increases, in fact could double the effective contact area by means of yielding due to flexibility.